# Show “Save As” dialogbox in Mac excel 2011 using vba

Tags: excel, macos, vba

How to show save as dialog box with xlsm as default save as file type in mac excel 2011?

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
```

works fine in windows. But it throws error in Mac

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are some features that do not work on MacOS, try this as an alternative:

```
Dim saveName As Variant

saveName = Application.GetSaveAsFileName()

If Not saveName = False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs CStr(saveName)
Else
    MsgBox "File not saved!"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But it is a template file. It shows the default save as type as All Files. But I want to show default save as type as xlsm in save as dialog. Is it that possible